# How (strategy) to unit test properties (get/set) in BDD style?

Tags: unit-testing, bdd, xunit.net, context-specification

I have a class (of many) that have properties.  Some have logic in them and some don't.  Assuming I want to test these properties, how do I go about doing that?

Recently, I've been interested in BDD style for creating unit tests.

see [here](http://iridescence.no/post/Extending-xUnit-with-a-Custom-ObservationAttribute-for-BDD-Style-Testing.aspx) and [here](http://www.bjoernrochel.de/tag/xunitbddextensions/).

So I'd do a setup of the context - basically create the SUT and load up whatever is needed.
Then in each Observation (test method), I'd verify that a particular property contains what it should contain.

Here's my question.  If the SUT has 20 properties, then do I create 20 Observations/Tests?  Could be more if one of the properties contained more interesting logic I guess.

```
[Observation]
public void should_load_FirstName()
{
    Assert.Equals<string>("John", SUT.FirstName);
}

[Observation]
public void should_load_LastName()
{
    Assert.Equals<string>("Doe", SUT.LastName);
}

[Observation]
public void should_load_FullName()
{
    Assert.Equals<string>("John Doe", SUT.FullName);
}
```

But would it be better if aggregated the simple ones in a single observation?

```
[Observation]
public void should_load_properties()
{
    Assert.Equals<string>("John", SUT.FirstName);
    Assert.Equals<string>("Doe", SUT.LastName);
    Assert.Equals<string>("John Doe", SUT.FullName);
}
```

Or what if I used a custom attribute (that can be applied multiple times to a method).  So that I can possible do, something like:

```
[Observation(PropertyName="FirstName", PropertyValue="John")]
[Observation(PropertyName="LastName", PropertyValue="Doe")]
[Observation(PropertyName="FullName", PropertyValue="John Doe")]
public void should_load_properties()
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In general you should strive after having only one *logical* assertion per test. The excellent book [xUnit Test Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054) contains a good discussion about that, but the salient point is that it makes it easier to understand where a violation occurs if there's only one reason a test can fail. That's probably a bit more relevant for Regression Testing than BDD, though...

All this implies that your option of writing a single test that verifies all properties is probably the least attractive, although you *could* argue that verifying all properties is a single logical assertion...

A more central tenet of xDD (TDD, BDD, whatever) is that tests should act as **Executable Specifications**. In other words, it should be immediately apparent when you look at the test not only *what* is being tested, but also *why* the expected value is as it is. In your examples, it is not very clear why SUT.FirstName is expected to be "John" and not, say, "Jane".

If at all possible, I would write these tests to use [Derived Values](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/03/03/DerivedValuesEnsureExecutableSpecification.aspx) instead of hard-coded values.

For writable properties, I often write tests that simply verify that the getter returns the value assigned to the setter.

Fore read-only properties, I often write tests that verify that the value matches a constructor argument.

Such tests can be encapsulated into reusable test code that encapsulates common testing idioms. I'm currently working on a [library that can do just that](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=1650).

Comment: Thank Mark for the advice.  Way back when, your blog posts on CallContext helped me out a lot!
I followed the link to Derived Values on Meszaros's site and read about it (after yours).  I am not sure I'd go to the extreme of implementing it as you did for your Reverse example.  I think having a variable, expectedResult right next to the input and then just use the literal value.
In my case above, I hear you - it's not apparent but I am loading test data from local disk to create the SUT (it's an acceptance/interaction test).  I need to find a better way to specify the input values...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the other SubSpec syntax (the `[Specification]` example) - in that case, each one of `Assert`s at the end represents a separate execution of the test. I originally discounted the syntax as lambda abuse but like it now I've been using it for a while.