# TDD - Unit tests failing due to assumptions in the arrange phase

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, tdd

I'm doing (or trying to do) TDD to develop my business logic for an application.

I have a collection in one class that I expose as `IReadOnlyList`, because I want to make it clear that adding/removing from the list is prohibited. Instead I expose `AddItem` and `RemoveItem` methods, so that I can execute some other code when an item is added or removed. See example below.

```
public interface IBusinessItem { }
public interface IBusinessClass
{
    IReadOnlyList<IBusinessItem> Items { get; }

    void AddItem(IBusinessItem item);
    void RemoveItem(IBusinessItem item);
}
```

My problem arises when I try to follow the principle that my unit tests [should fail for one reason only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1542548/4351604). Unit testing my `RemoveItem` requires that I make use of `AddItem` in my test arrange phase. Therefore, my test can fail either because the `RemoveItem` does not remove an item as expected, or because the `AddItem` didn't work as expected so `RemoveItem` throws:

```
[Fact]
public void RemoveItemShouldRemoveItemFromItems()
{
    // Arrange
    var item = new MyBusinessItem();
    sut.AddItem(item);
    // Act
    sut.RemoveItem(item); // throws exception if sut.Items is empty
    // Assert
    Assert.Empty(sut.Items);
}
```

I'm thinking that my unit test would be less fragile if I could access `sut.Items.Add(item)`, instead of relying on `sut.AddItem(item)`, but I don't want to [change my public interface just for testing purposes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/126577).

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1093481/4351604) partially adresses my concerns. My interpretation of the answer (and one of [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann)'s comments to the answer) is that it is fine to invoke other methods in the arrange phase. But I feel like this could end up with a lot of tests that fails for other reasons than what they are actually testing.

**My question here is**: When doing TDD, is it acceptable to access the underlying `List.Add` (that is not part of my public interface) in order avoid dependency of the `AddItem` implementation in my `RemoveItem` tests?.

A few ways I can think of to access the underlying `List.Add`:

- Casting it in the test
- Changing the underlying private field to protected and create a mock that inherits from my BusinessClass and exposes that field
- Changing the underlying private field to internal and use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute

Comment: If You want to expose something, just create a Mock, Stub, ... version of it inheriting from the basic class. The inherited version may expose what You want. No need for InternalsVisibleTo.

Comment: I would suggest adding a constructor dedicated for tests that takes a collection of items. In the constructor initialize the underlying collection directly, without calling AddItem. That way your arrange phase won't depend on AddItem.